# Secure file upload example

Tags: php, security

The overall question is:  I need feedback on the security of the idea and the script.  Do I need to do more in raw code, or is this ok, taking into account my other information?

1. Let's assume these following first:

   - All images are stored on a subdomain (e.g. `images.example.com`)
   - The subdomain `images.example.com` does not have execute rights
   - The upload script is named upload.php and is located at `example.com`
   - I run a virus scanner on `images.example.com` every day
2. A simple upload script written in PHP:

   ```
   $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
   $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
   $extension = end($temp);
   if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
   || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
   || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
   || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
   || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
   || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
   && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
   && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
     {
     if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
       {
       echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
       }
     else
       {  
       if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
         {
         echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
         }
       else
         {
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
         "images.example.com/" . randomName() .$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
         }
       }
     }
   else
     {
     echo "Invalid file";
     }
   ```

   The script is demonstrating my thoughts; nothing more.
3. So from what I understand now, all images uploaded cant do any harm to example.com, even if they contain `injected code`?
4. Do I not need to do a `exif` or `Fileinfo` check since I put the files on a subdomain?
5. I've assumed a lot of things.  Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would consider is using functions so that it becomes easier readable.

```
function hasAllowedExtension($filename); // returns bool
function isAllowedType($filetype); // returns bool
```

That way you can shorten the first lines to

```
$file = $_FILES["file"];
if (hasAllowedExtension($file["name"]) && isAllowedType($file["type"]) && $file["size"] < 20000) {
```

which is much more readable.

---

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
```

[There are better and easier ways](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

---

Also consider making all of this into a function which you only either hand the name of the file `$_FILES[$filename]` or the file (from `$_FILES`) directly.

---

```
echo "Invalid file";
```

A `die` might be appropriate here. `die` will also print a message but has the added bonus that it immediately stops execution and it is easier to understand that this is really a stopper.

```
die("Invalid file.");
```

---

I couldn't see any gaping holes in it except for only one thing: I can't remember and couldn't find out if `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` is safe or not. So check if this value can contain path separators or not. And by check I mean, read the documentation carefully.

---

Also it seems like you're checking for the file in a different location/under a different name than you actually save it as.

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
...
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "images.example.com/" . randomName() .$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Hey Bobby :) Do you have any comments on the security aspect of it all?

Comment: Only that name could contain anything, otherwise it looks good to me (at least I don't see anything), as long as the server is correctly configured (does not allow uploads of 500MB or so). I don't know  what `randomName()` returns, but better make sure that this never collides.

Comment: Ok, so yea.. I was thinking uploads of 5-50MB max.  randomName() is just a function that returns a random name to put infront of the original name.  But i might even just do a totally random name.

Comment: I don't see anything else, that doesn't meant that there isn't, though. Wait a moment, are you checking for the existence of `/uploaded/filename.ext` but then copying it to `/uploads/randomstuffFilename.ext`?

Comment: Ah the existence of a file on the subdomain.. forgot that :-)  That will ofc have to be implemented :)